# Creating a PHP checkout system

Tags: php, class, checkout

I'm trying to create a *fairly simple* PHP checkout system.

The table of information I'm using is:

**Product Code        Name            Price**
       SW1                Sandwich         £3.11
       CL1                 Chocolate        £5.00
       CF1                   Coffee           £11.23

My code is:

```
class Product {
    public $name;
    public $price;

    public function __construct($name, $price) {
        $this->item = $name;
        $this->price = $price;
  }
} class Checkout {
    protected $shopping_cart;

    public function scan(Product $product) {
        $shopping_cart[] = $product;
    }

    public function total() {
    // Goes through the shopping cart and sums up the price of the contents
        return array_reduce(
            $this->shopping_cart,
            function($total, $item) {
                return $total + $item->price;
            },
            0
        );
    }
}

$pay = new Checkout();
$pay->scan(new Product("Sandwich", 3.11));
$pay->scan(new Product("Chocolate", 5));
$pay->scan(new Product("Coffee", 11.23));
$price = $pay->total();
```

What I'd like to do is add a pricing rule to some items. For example, I'd like sandwiches to be buy-one-get-one-free and chocolates to have a bulk purchase discount.
Not sure if it'd work, but I'm thinking I should add something like this:

```
$SW1 = new Checkout("Sandwich", 3.11);
$CL1 = new Checkout("Chocolate", 5);
$CF1 = new Checkout("Coffee", 11.23);

if(scan($SW1 % 2 == 0)) {
    $price = $price / 2;
}
elseif(scan($SW1 == 1)) {
}
else {
    $price = $price / 2 + $price;
}

if(scan($CL1 >= 3 && $CL1 % 3 == 0)) {
    $price = $price - .50;
}
else {
// insert logic to make sure purchases that include more than 3 items, though not divisible by 3, are also discounted accordingly.
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Also if anyone knows how I could test this code, that'd be great ☺.

Comment: Trying to build your own ecommerce system, if you're going to use it in production is probably a really bad idea. You're better off extending an existing system.


Also, you're supposed to at least write the code and then ask for help when you get stuck, not ask people to write your code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a 'Discount' interface that can be applied to the product and/or the checkout. For example:

```
interface IDiscount {
  public function apply(&$amount);
}

class Discount_HalfOff implements IDiscount {
  public function apply(&$amount) {
    $amount /= 2;
  }
}

class Discount_FixedAmount implements IDiscount {
  private $amount;

  public function __construct($amount) {
    $this->amount = $amount;
  }

  public function apply(&$amount) {
    $amount -= $this->amount;
  }
}

class Product {
  private $discounts = [];

  public function __construct($name, $price) {
    $this->item  = $name;
    $this->price = $price;
  }

  public function addDiscount(IDiscount $discount) {
    $this->discounts[] = $discount;
  }

  public function getPrice() {
    $price = $this->price;
    foreach($this->discounts as $discount)
      $discount->apply($price);
    return $price;        
  }
}

class Checkout {
  private $contents  = [];
  private $discounts = [];

  public function addDiscount(IDiscount $discount) {
    $this->discounts[] = $discount;
  }

  public function scan(Product $product) {
    $this->contents[] = $product;
  }

  public function getCount() {
    return count($this->contents);
  }

  public function getTotal() {
    $ttl = 0;
    foreach($this->contents as $product)
      $ttl += $product->getPrice();

    foreach($this->discounts as $discount)
      $discount->apply($ttl);

    return $ttl;
  }
}

$sandwich = new Product('Sandwich', 3.11);
$sandwich->addDiscount(new Discount_HalfOff());

$checkout = new Checkout();
$checkout->scan($sandwich);

// this logic could be included into the Checkout class directly, depends on your use case.
if ($checkout->getCount() > 3) {
  if ($checkout->getCount() % 3 == 0)
    $checkout->addDiscount(new Discount_FixedAmount(0.50));
  } else {
    // insert logic to make sure purchases that include more than 3 items, though not divisible by 3, are also discounted accordingly.
  }
}

echo $checkout->getTotal() . "\n";
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I think I understand this well enough. Just wondering if it would be possible to for the checkout to be something like: $checkout->scan($sandwich, $chocolate); or would it have to be more like $checkout->scan($sandwich); $checkout->scan($chocolate); Thanks!

Comment: It is certainly possible, two methods... either pass an array of products to scan, or use `func_get_args` to retrieve the list of arguments passed to the method.